# React: When using Redux, where would I put my constants that are needed for my data lookup?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css';
import '../css/Input.css'
import { connect} from 'react-redux';

const countries = {
  China: 
    {"image": './typeI.jpg',
    "flag": "https://www.free-country-flags.com/countries/China/1/large/China.png",
    "otherCountries": ["Argentina", "Australia", "Fiji", "New Zealand", "Papa New Guinea", "Samoa", "Tonga"],
    },
  Australia: 
    {"image":'./typeI.jpg',
    "flag": "https://www.free-country-flags.com/countries/Australia/1/large/Australia.png",
    "otherCountries": ["Argentina", "China", "Fiji", "New Zealand", "Papa New Guinea", "Samoa", "Tonga"],
    },
  United_Kingdom: 
    {"image":'./typeG.jpg',
    "flag": "https://www.free-country-flags.com/countries/United_Kingdom/1/large/United_Kingdom.png",
    "otherCountries": ["Ireland", "Hong Kong", "Kenya", "Malaysia", "Malta", "Scotland", "Saudia Arabia", "Singapore", "UAE", "Wales"],
    }

}

class Input extends Component {
  handleChange = (selectedOption) => {

   this.setState({ 
     selectedOption,
     image: countries[selectedOption.value].image,
     plugType: countries[selectedOption.value].plugType,
     flag: countries[selectedOption.value].flag,
     otherCountries: countries[selectedOption.value].otherCountries,
     voltage: countries[selectedOption.value].voltage,
     plugs: countries[selectedOption.value].plugs,
     link: countries[selectedOption.value].link

  });

}
  render() {

  <div key="input" className="input">

    <div>
      <Select
        name="form-field-name"
        value={selectedOption}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        options={[
          { value: 'United_Kingdom', label: 'United Kingdom' },
          { value: 'China', label: 'China' },
          { value: 'Australia', label: 'Australia' },
        ]}
.....
```

all my data relies on using the selectedOption value to look up the country in my countries constant to get the right piece of data. ex: 
 `countries[selectedOption.value].image`

so now I want to remove the whole `setState` portion and use dispatch.
So I'd put this in for starters: `this.props.dispatch({ type: "SET_COUNTRY", data: selectedOption});` In that instance, I'm passing in `selectedOption` but then I'd have to get the value by getting it from my countries constant:  `countries[action.data.value].image` inside the reducer.

Should that be in my reducers file and have that lookup happen there? or should the data look up happen before hand and be passed in the dispatch action ?

Comment: Hi,
If you are using [ducks structure](https://github.com/erikras/ducks-modular-redux) for your redux, I think, that better way to organise this case is something like that:
In `constant.js` you have your choices.
In `action.js` you have action which make selection and dispatch country to reducer.
And the better way in your component map or reduce choices from `constant.js` to `options` props.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to **re-organize** your questions and you can refer to "[What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).